# Why this batch transcation in failing in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React Native for my app and I am doing a batch transaction which is failing on the second batch where I am setting :

```
let rriNshpiUserCollection = await firestore().collection('myDoc').doc(login_uid);
    let privateDoc = await firestore().collection('myDoc').doc(login_uid).collection('private');
    let batch = firestore().batch();

        batch.update(rriNshpiUserCollection, {
            addCoord: this.state.location,
            last_location: this.state.location,
            device_id: this.state.device_id,
            update_time: timeStamp,
            act: 1
        });
        batch.set(privateDoc, { // its failing here
            loc: this.state.location,
            time: timeStamp
        });
```

**Error :**

> **Error: firebase.firestore.batch().set(*) 'documentRef' expected instance of a DocumentReference.**

Can you tell what's wrong with that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from this code:

```
batch.set(privateDoc, {
    loc: this.state.location,
    time: timeStamp
});
```

The reason is that `privateDoc` is a reference to a collection, and you can't call `set` on a collection (or `batch.set` with a collection).

If you want to add a new document to the `private` collection, you can create a reference for that with:

```
batch.set(privateDoc.doc(), {
    loc: this.state.location,
    time: timeStamp
});
```

Or (and probably better):

```
let privateDoc = firestore().collection('myDoc').doc(login_uid)
                            .collection('private').doc();
batch.set(privateDoc, {
    loc: this.state.location,
    time: timeStamp
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `privateDoc` is a CollectionRefernce, but the error message is telling you that a DocumentReference is required.  A transaction must operation on individual documents.